# Remove a drive from Windows Storage Pool without losing data

Tags: windows, windows-8, storage, storage-spaces

I have a Windows Storage Pool with a 3TB drive and a 1.5TB drive. I want to move all the data from the 1.5TB drive to the (45% full) 3TB drive and then remove the 1.5TB drive. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

sure easiest way is if you  have a third drive "spare drive" (temporarily or trusted cloud /nfs  storage somewhere).

1) backup (even tarball/ zip ) the 1.5tb up onto the "spare drive"
2) then pull the entry(ies) for it in the pool
3) shutdown & reboot

Comment: If I had a spare drive, I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: local cloud (i.e. NAS Storage) or dropbox/gdrive or similar NOT an option then ?

Comment: No, uploading/downloading 1.5 TB of data to drive/dropbox would be both too expensive and too time consuming. And this server IS my NAS.